# Is there a function that will quickly sort a file in C?

Tags: c, file, function, sorting

Right, I'm writing some code using databases, and someone at my school was talking about some specific command that could automatically get a file and sort it.

I think I have a grasp on how to sort this file manually, but it requires a lot of work, so I was wondering if anyone knew this function.

edit: using DEV C++ , Library #stdio.h and # conio.h , (i can add the extra library if necessary) no idea what the specific complier is however.

Comment: `perl`? `sort`? Writing a C program *is* a lot of work, comparatively.

Comment: What os are you using?

Comment: Are you looking for a shell command to do this, or are you trying to write your own implementation in C?

Comment: @mattingly890 No idea what a shell command is, I'm trying to find the default function (such as getch(); or clrscr(); that can do it

Comment: qsort() can sort a file.  You would have to set-up a pointer array like char **file.  Where each pointer points to a line of input, than you just give the file pointer to qsort and it will sort it just like the unix default sort would do.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "sorting a file".

Comment: @juanchopanza taking all numerical values and sticking them in order.

Comment: @Carlise my files are 512 long, would that help?

Comment: OK, then put that in your question, with an short example of a file you want to sort. We're not mind readers.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/27695941/841108

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming your input file is data.txt (Linux), you can use the system command `sort`:

```
sort data.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: If it has to be in C, then the syntax is `system("sort data.txt > output.txt")`

Comment: @WhipItOut: `sort` is a system or shell command (to be executed from the command line). It's a standalone program, not a C/C++ function.

Comment: Cannot access file because it is being used by another process...

Comment: @WhipItOut that means you're running on windows, prettymuc the only solution is to close the file

Comment: @Jasen so I can't use this on windows? is there a windows solution?

Comment: Not that I  know of. windows file locking blocks access to files that are in use. Maybe someone has asked that question on this site already?

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned there is `sort` command in Unix:

```
sort myfile.txt
```

see `man sort` for more options.

And there is `SORT` command on Windows:

```
sort myfile.txt
```

or

```
SORT myfile.txt
```

for more help see: http://www.computerhope.com/sorthlp.htm

With that you could write simple C program that would use those commands.

```
// sort.system.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc != 2) { // expecting one argument, file which we will sort
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: sort [FILE]\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  int length = 5 + strlen(argv[1]) + 1; // length of "sort " is 5.
  char *command = (char *) calloc(length, sizeof(char));
  sprintf(command, "sort %s", argv[1]);

  int ret = system(command);

  return ret;
}
```

Here we just expect from user to enter file he wants to sort and then we are using this file and just give it to `sort` command. But first we need to make sure that user actually entered something. That is why we have `if` on beginning of `main` function.

Second approach would be to write `sort` command ourself. The fun starts here. :D

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 1000000

// compare function for qsort function
int compare (const void *a, const void *b) {
  const char **s1 = (const char **) a;
  const char **s2 = (const char **) b;
  return strcmp(*s1, *s2);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc != 2) { // expecting one argument, file which we will sort
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: sort [FILE]\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  char *filename = argv[1]; // name of file to sort
  FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r"); // trying to open that file
  if (file == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file %s\n", filename);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  int size = 16; // initial size of lines container
  char **lines = (char **) calloc(size, sizeof(char *)); // lines container
  if (lines == NULL) { // safety check
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate the requested block of memory\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  // buffer where we will store every line before putting it into line container
  char *buffer = (char *) calloc(MAX_LINE_LENGTH + 1, sizeof(char));
  if (buffer == NULL) { // safety check
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate the requested block of memory\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  int counter = 0; // line counter, counts how many lines we have readed

  // reading whole line into buffer
  while(fgets(buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH + 1, file) != NULL) {
    // measuring line length with strlen and adding 1 for '\0'
    int length = strlen(buffer);
    if (buffer[length - 1] == '\n') { // remove '\n' on end of line
      // replace '\n' with '\0', thus '\0' already included into length
      buffer[length - 1] = '\0';
    } else {
      length++; // include '\0'
    }

    // if our lines container is not large enough we will double its size
    if (counter + 1 == size) {
      size *= 2;
      lines = (char **) realloc(lines, size*sizeof(char *));
      if (lines == NULL) { // safety check
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate the requested block of memory\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
    }

    // allocating space for line
    lines[counter] = (char *) malloc(length*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(lines[counter], buffer);

    counter++;
  }

  // using qsort function from stdlib.h
  qsort(lines, counter, sizeof(char *), compare);

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    puts(lines[i]);
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Idea is to have some dynamic "lines container" whose initial size is 16. Every time we see that we need more space for storing our lines, we double the size of our "lines container".

Also, we have some buffer that we use to store every line and then we copy that line into next line container slot.

Here I limited size of one line to 10^6 characters. But you could dynamically allocate space for buffer too by using `ftell` and `fseek` functions. I suggest you to do that for practice. :)

For actual sorting of strings we are using `qsort` function from `stdlib.h`:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/

Comment: Note: `while(fscanf(file, "%[^\n] ", buffer)` does _not_ read anything if the first char is `'\n'`.  So if the file started with `'\n'`, --> infinite loop as `fscanf()` would return 0 and the loop would process `""`.  Suggest `fgets()`.

Comment: Corner issue remains with new change: If the last line does not end with a `'\n'`, then if the last line is sorted to another place, it will have no `\n` at its end and then it and the following line will appear as one - unclear as how to best handle.  Other pedantic issues include embedded `'\0'` and variant EOL types.  I am impressed with your sort routine, but like weddings, the details drive one crazy.

Comment: @chux Thanks for pointing that out. I have removed '\n' on end of every line.

Comment: @WhipItOut if there is something that you do not understand, you should ask :)

Comment: @HermanZvonimirDošilović "for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) { " comes up with the error "75 G:\Sorter\sort 3.c 'for' loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode "

Comment: @WhipItOut I am compiling it with `-std=c99` flag. I now edited my answer. I just declared __i__ outside `for` loop. There should be no errors now. :)

Comment: @HermanZvonimirDošilović and now I just insert the file name?

Comment: @WhipItOut when you compile your code, you should get file <name of your source>.exe (for example if name of your __c__ file is sort.c, then you should get sort.exe file when you compile it in DEV C++). Now, open cmd in that folder where you have .exe file, and start your program like this "sort.exe myfile.txt" (this is just an example, use real names). :)