# Sorting a C file

Tags: c, file, sorting

Right so I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27692282/is-there-a-function-that-will-quickly-sort-a-file-in-c/27694281#27694281) how I can sort my c file, and this was the coded response I created.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <conio.h>

 int main()
 {     
     FILE *fN;
     FILE *fS;

     fN=fopen("Numbers.txt","r");
     fS=fopen("Sorted.txt","w");
     system("sort Numbers.txt > Sorted.txt");
     getch();
     fclose(fS);
     fclose(fN);
 }
```

This always comes up with the same error message: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

does this mean I show change the libraries?, I'm really confused to why there is an error.

Comment: The title of the question is a bit misleading, since it seems like you're trying to sort a file _using C_, not _sort a C file_. Anyway, I don't see why you're using `fopen` and `fclose` since the `sort` command will take care of opening and closing the files.

Comment: You're opening them in your program, which is blocking `sort` from accessing the `sorted.txt`. Why are you opening them in your program if you're not going to use them in your program? The entire body of your main could be just the line with `system`.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks.... although I guess it isn't that obvious really.

Comment: It is that obvious. You've opened `Sorted .txt` with `fopen()`, and then immediately try to overwrite it by your call to `system` with `sort` redirected to `Sorted.txt` as well, which will fail because of your call to `fopen()`.

Comment: @KenWhite Woah, alright mr Major league programmer, sorry for being such a novice

Comment: @ryyker he called out something being obvious, how am I supposed to know if a command/function has a set open and close clause if I haven't dealt with them before?

Comment: @ryyker when the guy is being condescending, yeah. I don't know how these things work, that's why I posted a question here, my boss/co-workers also aren't going to pretty much call me stupid for not noticing a flaw in my system

Comment: There was no offense intended in either of my previous comments. I tried to be helpful by explaining what the problem was with the code you've posted. Sorry for trying to help. I'll try not to make the same mistake again.

Answer (score 2):

The code that you're posting above fundamentally uses the `sort` command-line utility to do the sorting. When you write

```
system("sort Numbers.txt > Sorted.txt");
```

you're invoking `sort` on the `Numbers.txt` file, then redirecting the output of the command to the file `Sorted.txt`.

The problem with your code is that before you try to do this, you're writing

```
fS=fopen("Sorted.txt","w");
```

This opens `Sorted.txt` for writing, which on most operating systems will lock the file from writing by any other process - including your `sort` process. To fix this, just eliminate all the `fopen` and `fclose` calls and just write

```
int main() {
    system("sort Numbers.txt > Sorted.txt");
}
```

In fairness, if this is all that your program does, just execute the above command from the command line. If you're doing this as a subroutine, though, just use the `system` command and don't do any manual `fopen` or `fclose` calls.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah , I didn't realise it opened the files from inside the function, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file is not too large (e.g. a few dozens of megabytes at most, or a few gigabytes on a powerful desktop with 16GBytes RAM) so its content fits in memory, you could read it line by line using a loop on [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) (or else `fgets` on some suitably large buffer), [strdup(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) each read line and put it in some dynamically allocated (using [calloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/calloc.3.html) or [realloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realloc.3.html)) array of pointers, then invoke [qsort(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html) on that array using a compare function built above [strcmp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html) if you want to sort strings.

<sup>If you do it as explained above, your don't depend on any *external* `sort` command, which might not be available on all systems.</sup>

If the file contains only numbers, read them using [fscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3.html) (or `sscanf` or `strtoll` or `strtod` on each line) and make your own compare function.

Your issue is probably that on your operating system a file cannot be opened by several processes (on most [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posix) systems this is permitted). Either `fopen` the `Sorted.txt` file *after* running the `sort` command, or avoid running an external command (which is also an external dependency) by coding as I said (reading into an array and `qsort`ing it)

If working on floating point numbers, read [the floating point guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/) (i.e. *What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*), and be aware of [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)s.

Notice also that `<conio.h>` is *not* a standard header: my system (Linux) don't have it. You probably don't need it (and you probably don't need to call `getch`)

If coding in C++11 you could use [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)

If using [SQLite](http://sqlite.org) or some real [SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) database (e.g. [PostgreSQL](http://postgresql.org/) ...) you could have an appropriate database schema and issue the appropriate SQL request (with `SELECT` ... `ORDER BY` ....). Don't forget the appropriate indexes.

Comment: Yes, since the compare function to `qsort` is user provided. Just make it appropriate for your needs